# Report Services Percentage calculation

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to write an expression in SQL Reporting Services that evaluates 2 fields and works out the percentage value of one of them.

Basically:

```
Fields!Value.Value (numeric value) + Fields!StandardDuty.Value (% value)
```

An example of this would be (if keyed into a calculator)

```
39792.82(Fields!Value.Value ) + 2.7%(Fields!StandardDuty.Value )  = 1074.40614
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to create your expression like this:

```
=Fields!yourFirstColumn.Value*(Fields!yourSecondColumn.Value/100)
```

I just tested this using the values, you provided above and returned `1074.40614`